# Confluent Kafka REST Proxy streaming methods

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to use Confluent Kafka streaming data platform using REST Proxy.

I have seen the documentation from the following path,

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html

They have various steaming method using REST Proxy APIs:

I assume that "Produce and Consume Binary Messages" is for streaming Media files or other files?

I assume "Produce and Consume JSON Messages" is for streaming Json data?

I have a doubt that what is the exact difference between "Produce and Consume JSON Messages" Vs "Produce and Consume Avro Messages" vs "Produce and Consume Binary Messages".

Could someone please explain me, as they don't have a detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

All Kafka data is binary data. Avro is one type of binary data that just happens to have a structured schema.

Files are also binary, but Kafka is not intended for file transfer - e.g. 1) there is a max message size in Kafka protocol, 2) Kafka is meant to horizontally scale, and files shouldn't be spread across partitions, 3) and you can't easily determine where a file start and ends if it is broken apart.

The binary format show in the REST Proxy docs are base64 strings, sent as text, but decoded and stored on the broker in raw binary. In other words, if you have a file that can be encoded as a base64 string that's smaller than the payload limit, then sure, you could send it, but that's not the primary purpose of the format - rather for custom formats that can be expressed as string representations, that cannot be converted to JSON or Avro for technical (or historical) reasons.

JSON and other human-readable formats are plain-text.